# The direction of turn of a coil

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, conventions

[image: coil image]

I'm confused about how the coil is turned. If the magnet is brought closer to the coil then the first coil at A should become North ( if viewed from magnet's side). But to find direction of current I need to know if the coil's one wire is above the second or second is above one. The current should be anticlockwise at A ( again when viewed from magnet ) but then problem of coil comes that current will now flow from A to B or B to A. I just need to know how the coil is bent. I know I'm asking such a question but please help.

Comment: I think the picture makes the most sense if the uppermost bit of each loop is furthest away from us.  So, viewed from above, the winding is antclockwise.

Comment: As drawn you o decided on the sense of the windings without more information.  It is an ambiguous diagram.